# PHP: search substring within a string using preg_match?

Tags: php, search, preg-match, substring

Im trying to create a function to check for a substring within a string in php.

```
public static function stringCheck ($string, $substring) {
  $patern = "/".$substring."/";

  if (preg_match($substring, string) {
    return true;
  }
  else return false;
}
```

but if i enter a special character used in preg_match (^.[$()|*+?{) it screws up the search.

I tried something like the code below but that didnt work

```
$speicalChar = '/(\^|\.|\[|\$|\(|\)|\*|\+|\?|\{|\\)/';
```

Anyone have a solution or maybe an alternative to preg_match. keep in mind that i want to be able to check for symbols too. I tried using strstr but had issues with symbols.

Thanks =]

Comment: 1) Its not $patern, its $pattern. 2) You've forgotten an $, its not "if (preg_match($substring, string)" it is "if (preg_match($pattern, $string)" & you dont need the else, it can basicly be: "if (preg_match($pattern, $string) { return true; } return false;" because it the if condition is true, the return will be true end this will stop the function, else it will return false and stop the function.

Comment: Or `return (bool) preg_match($pattern, $string);`

Comment: ya this isn't my actual code, i just wrote a quick example so my bad on the syntax errors. thanks, i mainly just wanted to know how to check for speical characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/' . preg_quote($substring, '/') . '/';
```

This escapes special characters for you. Also pass in `'/'` so it gets escaped as well since you're using it as a delimiter.

Another thing, fixes for some typos in your if condition:

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
```

Comment: wow thanks alot boltclock! preg_quote is exactly what im looking for =]

Answer (score 4):

Is there any reason why you want to use `preg_match` ? Does it have to be a regular expression? What about [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)?

> Returns the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack  string.

```
public static function stringCheck ($string, $substring) {
  return (strpos($string, $substring) !== false);
}
```

If you don't have a reason to use regular expressions, don't use them.

**Update**:

Regarding the comment about `public static`: Don't create classes to *collect* functions (it looks like you are doing this here). That does not make sense. Just create normal functions and include them in your scripts. Use classes for real OOP.
Btw. you should consider a more expressive name for your function. `stringCheck` is pretty vague (what does it check?).

Comment: @stereofrog: Well, I just copied the OPs method signature. Don't blame me! ;) :D

Comment: @stereofrog: how do you get such a nice, rounded float?